# How do I convert Morse code to ASCII text

Tags: c#, morse-code

Yes this is homework but I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out. So right now I am doing a project in which you convert plain text into morse code, I was able to do so and it was relatively easy. However, now I need to convert the morse code back into text and I've run into a roadblock. I am not sure if I should make a new dictionary and reverse the text and char or if I should just reverse the existing dictionary that I have already made. Also we're not allowed to use if or case statements which makes it a bit harder but not by too much.
Here is what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Morse_Code_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Dictionary<char, String> morse = new Dictionary<char, String>()
        {
            {' ', " /" },{',', " --..--" }, {'.', " .-.-.-" }, {'?'," ..--.."},{'0'," -----"},{'1', " .----"},
            {'2'," ..---"},{'3'," ...--"},{'4'," ....-"},{'5'," ....."},{'6'," -...."},{'7'," --..."},{'8'," ---.."},
            {'9'," ----." },{'a', " .-"}, {'b', " -..."},{'c'," -.-."},{'d'," -.."},{'e'," ."},{'f'," ..-."},
            {'g'," --."},{'h'," ...."},{'i'," .."},{'j'," .---"},{'k'," -.-"},{'l'," .-.."},{'m'," --"},{'n'," -."},
            {'o'," ---"},{'p'," .--."},{'q'," --.-"},{'r'," .-."},{'s'," ..."},{'t'," -"},{'u'," ..-"},{'v'," ...-"},{'w'," .--"},
            {'x'," -..-"},{'y'," -.--"},{'z'," --.."}
        };
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void convertToMorseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string input = morseTextBox.Text;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
            {
                var t = input[index];
                input = input.ToLower();
                string morseValue;

                morse.TryGetValue(t, out morseValue);
                sb.Append(morseValue);

            }
            textToMorseLabel.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        private void morseToTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //This is where I want to convert
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            morseTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void morseClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can help guide me in the right direction that would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cant you just reverse the encoding process to decode the morse code?

Comment: Since morse is multiple characters what you actually need is a tree structure that has dot and dash branches that leads to leaf nodes that give you the character.  Then you'd follow the tree brach for each morse character until you find your character.

Comment: Here's a site that explains the concept https://medium.com/swlh/how-tree-data-structures-help-us-understand-morse-code-a95f6f7f2219

Comment: the logic is quite different, you can reuse your knowledge of morse but not your data structures or code

Comment: before you write a dictionary with the same values use `var morseToAscii = morse.ToDictionary(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Value.Trim(), item.Key));` to just copy it with keys and values flipped. cause you used a space as seperator for the morse code just use `morseInput.Split(' ')` to get an array with all input chars. An alternative to the new dictonary would be something like `var asciiChar = morse.Where(item=>item.Value.Trim() == morseChar).FirstOrDefault()?.Key`. But I hope that you had solved your homework already by yourself :)

Comment: I appreaciate all of the help from you guys I was able to talk with my professor about it, he had a delayed response but eventually he was able to help me out and I got a decent grade.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a school project, I don't give you the code, but I will try to explain, how you can do it.

I suppose morse codes (in input) are separated by a space, so first use `String.Split(' ')` to get a `string[]` each with a morsecode string.

I also assume, that you're not familiar with 'Linq' (yet) - or are not allowed to use it, so now you iterate (with a `for` loop) through this array, then use a `for` loop to find the item in `morses` Dictionary that has the `value` equal to this morsecode and return the `key`.

Using this method you don't need an extra dictionary. However, if this was real code, you should create a reverse `Dictionary`, which is faster than this approach.